# many to many crud requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

So a typical crud would be like so.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProvidersController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(){}

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {}

    // POST api/provider
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Provider value){}

    // PUT api/provider/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]Provider value){}

    // DELETE api/provider/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id) {}
}
```

But I want to extend it to a many to many type resource.

Where I have paths like /api/provider/{id}/resolution [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE].

Do I do this in a different class or do I extend this one?  Can I just add it to this class?

I tried to do something like below but it seems like it shouldn't be in the same class.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProvidersController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(){}

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {}

    // POST api/provider
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Provider value){}

    // PUT api/provider/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]Provider value){}

    // DELETE api/provider/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id) {}

    Route["{providerId}/resources/"]
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(int providerId){}

    Route["{providerId}/resources/{id}"]
    public IActionResult<object> Get(int providerId, int id){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason move it to another controller. Off course you could move  but there will always be just this two get methods(Get(int providerId) and Get(int providerId, int id))

Comment: So if i moved it to another controller how would the route look?  


    [Route("api/provider/{providerId}/[controller]")]
    public class OtherController : Controller {  ?

Comment: api/resource/{providerId}/{id}